# Display a Model Field (CharField) as a Dynamic URL | Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Tags: python, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

My goal is to have the "listing" part of the path in ".com/listings/listing" be the dynamic **'address'** field of the model called "Listing".
("6226Bourbonais"is the address field example for this problem.)

**So I'm basically going for: .com/listings/6226Bourbonais**

I have successfully gotten the template to display with the primary key as the url, which is currently the auto-generated ID, an integer. 
But when I try to reverse engineer that to display the address field of the listing model instead, it gives me the error:

> **invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6226Bourbonais'**

**urls.py**

```
    from django.urls import path

    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
      path('', views.index, name='listings'),
      path('<str:listing_address>', views.listing, name='listing'),
      path('search', views.search, name='search'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
    def listing(request, listing_address):

      listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, id=listing_address)
      context = {
        'listing': listing,
      }
      return render(request, 'listings/listing.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
    class Listing(models.Model): 

      agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      address = models.CharField(max_length=
      year_built = models.IntegerField(default=1900)
      build_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)

...(etc.)
```

**markup snippet of the listing.html template**

```
    {% if listings %}
              {% for listing in listings %}
              <div class="col s12 l4">
                  <a href="{% url 'listing' listing.address %}" class="">
                    <div class="card z-depth-2">
                      <div class="card-image">
```

While the error does come up, when I look at the URL on the page, it is correct. "mysite.com/listings/6226Bourbonais"
So i'm thinking the routing is working, but the error has to do with Django not knowing what to do with a str versus an int.

I'm new to django, so any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there: you just need to use the address field as your lookup:

```
listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, address=listing_address)
```

Comment: Brilliant! - That worked. I was so close, yet so far, haha. Thanks.